# Return bool from a Background thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public bool function()
{
    bool doesExist = false;          
    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
        {
            // some work done here
        };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
            //somw logic here
            return doesExist;                               
        };
}
```

I want `doesExist` value for as a return value for function but I am getting intellisense error

> system.componentmodel. runworkercompletedeventhandler returns only void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

Why I am getting this error, How to return bool value?

Answer (score 2):

```
public bool function()
{
   bool doesExist = false;          
   BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

   worker.DoWork += (o, ea) =>
            {
                 // do some work
                 ea.Result = true; // set this as true if all goes well!
            };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, ea) =>
        {
              // since the boolean value is calculated here &
              // RunWorkerCompleted returns void
              // you can create a method with boolean parameter that handle the result.
              Another_Way_To_Return_Boolean(doesExist)


        };
} 


private void Another_Way_To_Return_Boolean(bool result)
{
    if (result)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: that'd be `ea.Result`, but yes. =)

Comment: @J.Steen - thnx! I am very much used to using `e` for `EventArg` then `ea`

Comment: doesExist value is calculated in worker.RunWorkerCompleted not in wprker.Dowork.  I need to reutrn value from worker.RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: @АндрейПро - return where ? `RunWorkerCompleted` cannot return as is prototyped as `public delegate void RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler( Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)`

Comment: so there is no way to make return value of function() equal to doesExist in  RunWorkerCompleted block

Comment: @АндрейПро -  `RunWorkerCompleted` is like event which is fired when work is complete, in simple words, you are not calling it, it is raise when something happens, so where would u return the value ?